# Why is Laylatul Qadr interpreted to hazrat Fatima?

Tags: shiism, hadith-interpretation, laylat-al-qadr, fatima-zahra

There are some hadiths which interpreted Laylatul Qadr to hazrat Fatima like the following.
Why is it interpreted to hazrat Fatima?

> **قال الصادق (علیه السلام)**:’’ انا انزلناه في لـيلة القـدر’’، الليلة
>   فاطـمه و القـدر الله فمن عرف    فاطمه حق معرفتها فقد ادرک ليلة القدر و
>   أنما سميت فاطمه لأن الخلق فطموا عن معرفتها…. **بحار الانوار جلد43**
>
> [Imam Jafar Sadiq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja%27far_al-Sadiq) said in interpretation of this verse  ’’ Indeed, We sent the Qur'an down during the Night of Decree’’ the night means 
>   Fatima  and the decree means Allah….

Comment: hadith source plz?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since hazrat Fatima is very eminent and just few achieve that understanding,Imam Sadiq (A.S.) interpreting this verse to hazrat Fatima and said: "Who knows Fatima the way it should,then could understand Laylatul Qadr.

Fatima is Laylatul Qadr of ahlul bayt and surat al-Qadr represent magnitude of her and is interpreted to hazrat Fatima through this reasons:

1. As Laylatul Qadr is a hidden night and only some of righteous will understand this night, accessing to the spiritual authority of Hazrat Zahra is such.
2. As Laylatul Qadr is one night but is better than a thousand nights,Fatima is a person but is Ummah and the Prophet 's Kosar.
3. As Laylatul Qadr worshiping is such as worshiping thirty thousand nights,knowing of Fatima Zahra is rewarded as laylatul Qadr worshiping and knowing Fatima cause knowing  Laylatul Qadr.
4. As in Laylatul Qadr,Qur'an was revealed,from 'Fatima Zahra',eleven Immaculates,eleven Imams and eleven Qur'an Orators has been revealed.
5. As Laylatul Qadr has sublime degrees,hazrat Fatima has sublime degrees,too.
6. And as Laylatul Qadr is still hidden among three nights,hazrat Fatima Zahra (SA) 's grave is hidden probably in three places: her house, Jannat al-Baqi, the distance between sanctuary and pulpit.

[Reference](http://shamim.valiasr-aj.com/include/VIEW.php?bankname=LIBLIST&code=118&RADIF=9)